# In welchen Regionen ist die dem-sein-Form gebräuchlich?

Tags: dative, dialect, regional, possessive

Als Alternative zum Genitiv gibt es das *dem-sein-*Konstrukt. (Keine Ahnung, wie man es sonst nennen sollte):

> Der Frau ihre Handtasche. Dem Fritz sein Schwager.

Wo ist diese Form gebräuchlich?

Comment: For non-native speakers: What we are discussing here is viewed as an abomination in High German. Do not try this at home :)

Comment: @Pekka: "do not try this at home" +1 :) Ein Freund von mir aus Taiwan behauptet übrigens, dass diese Form in seinem Deutschbuch (Marke Langenscheidt) verwendet wird. Ich glaube das ist, weil zu dem Zeitpunkt der Genitiv noch nicht erläutert wurde.

Comment: @poke: Jedem Land sein Genitiv! wie Bastian Sick und Ingrid Noll schrieben würden.

Comment: Wozu soll das `dem-sein`-Tag denn gut sein, außer für diese eine Frage? … und wirklich, "abomination" würde ich das nicht nennen, man wird eher ein bisschen belächelt, aber es ist eine ganz lustige Sprachvariation (solange man es nur manchmal humorvoll einsetzt und nicht aus Unwissenheit so spricht). Im Rheinland wird es auch verwendet.

Comment: Angesichts der vielen Antworten hätte man auch fragen können, in welchen Regionen das *"dem sein"* Konstrukt **nicht** vorkommt.

Comment: Ach ja, der [Wem-sing-Fall](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-wem-sein-brot-ich-ess-dem-sein-lied-ich-sing-a-415534.html)... - Aber diese Frage an sich scheint mir zu viele "richtige" Antworten zu provozieren, ich halte sie für nicht zielführend.

Comment: Naja, watt heisst schon jebräuchlisch. Wir hier sachen dat so, aber nur wenn mer platt reden. Aber ein Freund hat ein Foto von einem französischen Schloss, da steht im Schlafzimmer als Übersetzung "dem König sein Bett" - weiß leider nicht, was da auf Französisch stand.

Comment: Kenne das als Kölscher Wemsingten. "Wemsin Täsch is dät?" "Dem Franz sin Frau ihr Täsch. "

Comment: @Felix Dombek: Tja, in Österreich wird man belächelt (schwächere Gemüter könnten auch eingeschüchtert sein von der Intelligenz), wenn man den Genitiv statt der Pronominalkonstruktion verwendet. Man spricht am besten, wenn man aus Unwissenheit spricht. Denn überall, wo sich der Verstand einmischt, kommen törichte Konstrukte dabei raus.

Comment: @Pekka웃: However, non-natives who like to speak genuinely in the South German language area should use it.

Comment: In der Gosse! Ok - etwas freundlicher: Auf der Straße. :)

Comment: Ich denke, in diesem Umfeld ist es interessant zu beachten, dass es eine Eigenschaft der **französischen Sprache** ist, den Genitiv mit Dativ und einer Präposition zu umschreiben. Möglicherweise tritt deswegen die "dem sein"-Form vorzugsweise an der Sprachgrenze auf. Hier ein kurzer **rant** aus dem Grimmschen Wörterbuch: *... und noch eine andere wendung drängte sich ein, die eigentlich nichts als französisch gedacht ist, aber jetzt im unaufhaltsamen vordringen, keine ehre für unsern stil, d. h. mit von statt des dat., wie ein nach franz. art umschriebener gen.*

Comment: Diese Konstruktion wird auch in der luxemburgischen Sprache verwendet. 

Diese zählt historisch gesehen zu den deutschen Dialekten (zur Gruppe der moselfränkischen Dialekte).
Diese Feststellung fügt sich nahtlos an die bisherigen Antworten und bestreitet das bisher Gesagte keineswegs.

"Dem Lisa seng Wunneng ass grouss."
(_Lisas Wohnung ist groß._)
"Dem Lisa sengem Papp seng Wunneng ass grouss."
(_Die Wohnung von Lisas Vater ist groß._)

Comment: Diese Form heißt übrigens, nach dem Kabarettisten Becker (WDR/Köln) wenn ich mich recht entsinne, der Wemsingten. "Dat is dem Maathes sing Frau ihr Täsch" (das ist Matthias' Fraus Tasche/ die Tasche der Frau des Matthias), unterschieden vom Vonativ (die Tasche von der Frau vom Matthias).

Comment: Kölsch ; dem sing Frau jeht zum Dom

Comment: Es gibt noch Steigerungen: **Wem seine Jacke gehört 'n die?** (Olaf Schubert; 'n = denn) Hier im Ruhrpott kommt 'dem sein/e' / 'der ihr/e' vor, aber supergebräuchlich ist das nicht (mehr). Ich probier's mal aus: _Also, wat den Kuddi seine Schwägerin is, der ihr Neffe hat bei de Führerscheinprüfung dat Auto geschrottet._ Sowas wie 'ihm sein/e' dürfte hier ziemlich selten sein, 'ihr ihr/e' ist unmöglich. Es gab dazu übrigens mal 'ne AdA-Umfrage: http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/r10-f13g/

Comment: Die vorliegenden Antworten zeigen, dass die Frage eher "Wo ist diese Form **nicht** gebräuchlich" lauten sollte. Das sagt *Ihne Ihrn* Paul Frost. Vgl. [hier](https://www.projekt-gutenberg.org/niebergl/datter/datter11.html).

Comment: Brecht 1957 Furcht und Elend des Dritten Reiches, Suhrkamp, Seite 30: "Dem seine Partei hat gestern im Reichstag für Hitlers Außenpolitik gestimmt." Und @ccprog https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/71120/what-does-ich-habe-k%c3%b6nnen-mean-in-brecht-berlin-dialect sagt "Bavaria/Swabia [is] where Brecht grew up."

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In Schwaben und im Alemannischen und ich *glaube* im Schweizerdeutschen ist es definitiv ein fester Bestandteil der Sprache. Ich würde es deshalb vom Gefühl her nicht als reine umgangssprachliche Verkümmerung abtun, bin aber kein Experte.

Zu der Frage, was sie sind, sagt [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dativ):

> Possessiv-Konstruktionen [Bearbeiten]
>
> Besitzanzeigende Dativkonstruktionen nach dem Muster `Nominalphrase Possessivpronomen Substantiv Nominativ` (z. B. „Dem Hans sein Hut“) sind seit langem in den meisten deutschen Dialekten und der Umgangssprache verbreitet.
>
> Belegt sind sie seit althochdeutscher Zeit: „du uuart demo balderes uolon sin uuoz birenkit“ – „dem Fohlen sein Fuß“ (Merseburger Zaubersprüche). Die Nominalphrase kann dabei auch durch ein Demonstrativpronomen („dem sein Hut“) oder eine Interrogativpronomen („wem sein Hut“) repräsentiert werden. Ferner sind rekursiv ineinander gebettete Konstruktionen möglich („Der Frau ihrem Mann sein Hut“).
>
> In der Schriftsprache und der gehobenen Sprache sind diese Formen nicht üblich und gelten als ungrammatisch oder zumindest als stilistisch fragwürdig. Ausdruck findet diese Haltung in dem von Bastian Sick aufgegriffenen ironischen Sponti-Spruch „Der Dativ ist dem Genitiv sein Tod“.

Comment: @Tomalak: Wobei man streiten könnte, ob "Der Frau ihrem Mann sein Hut" rekursiv (also auch selbstbezüglich) oder einfach nur verschachtelt ist.

Comment: @FUZxxl Was die Besitzanzeige angeht (und darum geht es ja hier), ist es zumindest transitiv.

Comment: +1, aber: Statt *ist es ein fester Bestandteil der Sprache...* hätte ich lieber erwähnt gesehen, dass diese Dialekte im Prinzip keinen Genitiv kennen und es daher eine Ersatzform ist.

Comment: Im Donauschwäbischen (was sprachwissenschaftlich oft eher pfälzisch ist) ist diese Form üblich.  Das Jiddische kennt den Genitiv auch kaum mehr, aber ich würde sagen in den in NY-beheimateten Arten etabliert sich so langsam eine dem Englischen ähnliche Form.

Comment: Auch in Österreich und überhaupt im gesamten bairischen Sprachraum. Den Genitiv gibt's da nicht.

Comment: @FUZxxl ich hab's bei Wikipedia korrigiert

Answer (score 15):

Die Ersetzung des possessiven Genitivs durch den possessiven Dativ ist eine ganz natürliche Weiterentwicklung, die man in sehr vielen indoeuropäischen Sprachen beobachten kann. Folgende Beispiele zeigen, warum das so natürlich ist:

> Der Dieb hat der Frau ihre Handtasche gestohlen. (Der Dieb hat der Frau einen Gegenstand gestohlen.)
>   Die Rechnung hat dem Fritz sein Schwager bezahlt. (Die Rechnung hat dem Fritz ein Verwandter bezahlt.)

In Klammern habe ich jeweils einen weiteren Satz hinzugefügt, der dieselbe hochsprachliche Konstruktion verwendet – für den Fall, dass jemand nur die dialektale/umgangssprachliche Konstruktion mit dem possessiven Dativ sieht.

In manchen Sprachen ist die obige Konstruktion einfach nur eine mögliche Variante an Stelle der folgenden mit dem possessiven Genitiv:

> Der Dieb hat die Handtasche der Frau gestohlen.
>   Die Rechnung hat Fritz’ Schwager bezahlt.

In manchen Sprachen ist es aber – zumindest in bestimmten Fällen – unidiomatisch, den possessiven Genitiv zu benutzen, wenn man dasselbe auch mit einer Dativkonstruktion wie oben ausdrücken kann. Das kann man als den Beginn einer Entwicklung vom possessiven Genitiv zum possessiven Dativ interpretieren. Und in vielen Fällen ist es nicht dabei geblieben.

In den anderen westgermanischen Nationalsprachen Englisch und Niederländisch ist diese Entwicklung durch den fast völligen Verlust auch des Dativs inzwischen überholt. Aber in vielen deutschen Dialekten ist der Genitiv praktisch genauso tot wie im Niederländischen (d.h. existiert nur noch in erstarrten Ausdrücken), und **in allen deutschen Dialekten ist der possessive Dativ neben *von*-Konstruktionen eine Standardkonstruktion**.

Wer glaubt, dass das ein Symptom des Niedergangs der deutschen Sprache ist, sollte sich vielleicht klar machen, dass der possessive Dativ z.B. im klassischen Latein und Griechisch eine Standardkonstruktion ist, die man in praktisch allen deutschen Dialekten besser wiedergeben kann als im Standard-Hochdeutsch.

Abschweifung: Ein weiteres interessantes Phänomen in diesem Zusammenhang ist das hohe Ansehen, das der possessive Dativ im Englischen auf Grund eines Missverständnisses vorübergehend genoss. Durch die Reduzierung des Genitivs auf ein einheitliches *’s* (bzw. *’* bei Wörtern, die auf *s* enden) und den völligen Verlust von Dativendungen war der Weg frei, um *Fritz his brother-in-law* als ausgeschriebene Variante von *Fritz’ brother-in-law* zu interpretieren, und kurioserweise ebenso *the woman her handbag* als die ursprüngliche Langform von *the woman’s handbag*. In formalen Texten aus der betreffenden Zeit gibt es daher neben der heute noch üblichen Vermeidung von Kontraktionen wie *it’s* eine starke Tendenz, auch den sächsischen Genitiv durch den possessiven Dativ zu ersetzen. (Ich nenne das jetzt einfach mal so, auch wenn es im Englischen natürlich schon damals den Unterschied zwischen Nominativ, Akkusativ und Dativ nur noch bei Personalpronomen gab, so dass man ohne die Analogie zu Konstruktionen in anderen Sprachen genauso gut von einem possessiven Nominativ oder Akkusativ sprechen könnte.)

Die deutsche Standardsprache hinkt hier also der allgemeinen sprachlichen Entwicklung hinterher. Möglich ist das, weil im Deutschen, ähnlich wie z.B. im Französischen und anders als z.B. im Niederländischen und im Englischen, die literarische Sprache seit jeher und auch heute noch relativ stark von der Umgangssprache isoliert ist. Das hat den Vorteil, dass sich (u.A. durch die Rückwirkung der literarischen Sprache auf Umgangssprache und Dialekte) die Sprache insgesamt langsamer ändert und literarische Texte länger ohne Übersetzung verständlich bleiben. Andererseits hat es den Nachteil, dass viele Kinder in der Schule das Lesen und Schreiben quasi in einer Fremdsprache lernen und auch manche Erwachsene Schwierigkeiten haben, sich schriftlich auszudrücken.

Irgendwann, vielleicht in relativ ferner Zukunft, werden diese Probleme überhandnehmen und man wird die dann herrschende Umgangssprache (oder eine frühere Form) zur Basis einer neuen Schriftsprache nehmen – so, wie sich z.B. im Italien des 16. Jahrhunderts eine italienische Schriftsprache auf der Basis der Werke von Dialektautoren des 13./14. Jahrhunderts wie Dante Alighieri als längst überfälliger Ersatz für das Lateinische durchsetzte. Schon vorher waren allerdings andere Schriftsprachen auf der Basis von Dialekten des Lateinischen entstanden, wie z.B. Französisch, Provençalisch oder Spanisch. Das zeigt, dass das Deutsche bei einer solchen Entwicklung weiter in Regionalsprachen zerfallen könnte. (Ähnlich, wie sich ja auch Niederländisch und Jiddisch bereits von der deutschen Sprachgemeinschaft abgekoppelt haben und der Prozess in der Schweiz momentan läuft. Aber dann wird man auch in Hamburg und München keine gemeinsame (deutsche) Schriftsprache mehr haben.)

Der unnötig große Abstand, den die deutsche Schriftsprache durch ihren Konservatismus von den nord- und den anderen westgermanischen Sprachen hat, könnte in der heutigen mobilen Welt aber schon vorher dazu führen, dass sich Deutsch als eine der (momentan drei) EU-Arbeitssprachen letztlich nicht bewährt und in einem vereinigten Europa am Ende eine marginale Rolle ähnlich dem Rätoromanischen in der Schweiz spielt. Wenn es so kommt, werden die meisten Kinder in der Schule wahrscheinlich erst einmal auf Englisch schreiben lernen.

Comment: Es ist doch was Schönes, wenn man eine profane Alltagssprache und eine Dichtersprache mit einer sofort erkennbaren Attitüde hat. Die Frage ist nur, von wo man die Standardsprache bezieht.

Answer (score 9):

I think it's most commonly associated with the "Ruhrgebiet", better known as "Ruhrpott" (informal) in Germany, where "Ruhrpott" is more closely associated to a certain social setting in which the infamous "dem sein"-form is used.

As far as I can tell it's usually frowned upon and should be avoided.

Comment: In the Ruhrpott, it gets really crazy when this is combined with the *Rheinische Verlaufsform*.

Comment: Ich bin grad einen Kommentar am Schreiben dran.

Comment: *Dem Schantall sein Freund is grad am in Knast komm dabei.* Mostly preceded by an introductory *Hömma!*

Comment: No, it appears in the whole South German language area.

Answer (score 8):

Aside of the already mentioned regions, that form is almost standard in the **Saarland**.

Answer (score 8):

Diese Form ist ein wichtiger und unabdingbarer Bestandteil vieler Schweizer Dialekte. In Berndeutsch zum Beispiel heisst es:

> Dere Frou iri Handtäsche. Am Fritz si
>   Schwager.

Und es ist schlicht **unmöglich**, dies in einem Genitiv-Satz zu sagen. Den Genitiv gibt es nicht in diesem Kontext. Das hat auch nichts mit verkümmerter Grammatik zu tun, Berndeutsch ist älter als das heutige Hochdeutsch.

Comment: Wieso gehen "Die Handtasche der Frau" und "Fritz' Schwager" nicht? Oder verstehe ich dich falsch?

Comment: Es gibt keinen korrekten Weg, dies zu sagen. Man müsste dann sagen: D Handtäsche vo dere Frou. Bei Namen gibt es in einigen Dialekten noch eine Genitiv-Form: Fritzens Schwager. Aber NIE Fritz' Schwager. Und das geht auch nicht für die Handtasche. NIE.

Comment: Ja, wir reden aber trotzdem von der Standardsprache, wo diese Konstruktion eigentlich unerhört ist.

Comment: Ein paar Leute hier scheinen nicht zu verstehen, dass es den Genitiv schlicht und einfach in meiner Muttersprache nicht gibt und auch nie gab. Da könnte man genau so gut fragen, warum dem Hochdeutschen der Instrumental fehlt. Das ist nun mal so, das ist das Wesen der Sprache.

Answer (score 8):

Die "dem-sein" Form erscheint auch in den Niederlanden, Flandern & Afrikaans.

> "Dem Mann sein Hut" ---> "de man zijn hoed" im Niederländisch.

Im Afrikaans ist diese Form die häufigste Possessiv-Form: "die man se hoed".
Also ist diese Form nicht nur in Deutschland gebräuchlich.

Comment: Interssant wäre, wie es denn im NL um den Genitiv bestellt ist, bzw. ob auch dort der Genitiv vom Dativ verdrängt wird.

Comment: Der Genitiv ist im NL fast verschwunden. Gibt nur die "von" und "dem-sein Formen. z.B. "De hoed des mans" (Der Hut des Mannes) ist möglich
aber klingt sehr, sehr veraltet. "De hoed van de man" (*Der Hut vom Mann") und die dem-sein Form sind richtig.

Answer (score 7):

Hier in Österreich (beziehungsweise Oberösterreich) kommt es durchaus häufig vor, dass man diese Konstrukte im täglichen Sprachgebrauch verwendet. Allerdings nur wenn gesprochen wird, geschrieben wird trotzdem Hochdeutsch/österreichisches Deutsch.

Gesprochen:

> Da Oma ia Hondtoschn
>   Am Fritz sei Schwoga

Geschrieben:

> Omas Handtasche/Die Handtasche von Oma
>   Der Schwager vom Fritz

Zusätzlich ist noch zu erwähnen, dass es hier meist nicht gut ankommt, wenn man beim Sprechen den Genitiv verwendet. Dadurch kann man sehr leicht als arrogant oder besserwisserisch eingeschätzt werden. Außerdem hört es sich für einen Österreicher einfach falsch an, wenn in einem Dialekt-Satz ein Genitiv vorkommt ;-)

Comment: Auch in dialektbefreiten Gegenden Wiens und seines größeren Umlands ist der Genitiv unerhört.

Answer (score 5):

Das sagen Menschen hier im Kölner Raum und in der Region Ruhr ebenfalls. Für diese Regionen kann ich es bejahen. Woher es kommt weiß ich nicht. Allerdings würde ich das auch eher als schlechten Stil betitteln wollen. ;)

Comment: Interessant wäre zu wissen, ob es im Ur-Kölsch vorkommt.

Comment: Ich habe es durch einen Rheinländer Kabarettisten als "Wemsingten" vorgestellt bekommen: "Wemsing Täsch es dät? Dem Pit singe Lis' ihre Täsch" o.s.ä. ("Dem Peter seine Elisabeth ihre Tasche", "From Pete, the Elli her bag").

Answer (score 4):

In Sachsen und Preussen (Brandenburg) ist das umgangssprachlich durchaus üblich.

Comment: …und bevor jemand nach Quellen fragt, ich komme aus der Gegend. ;)

Comment: Der Kommentar ist nicht hilfreich die Frage solide zu beantworten.

Comment: @grunwald: Inwiefern?? Er listet zwei Regionen auf, in denen diese Form gebräuchlich ist.

Comment: @grundwald: Definiere "nicht hilfreich" in diesem Kontext.

Comment: Can confirm Saxony, too!

Comment: In Brandenburg gilt dies als schlechtes Deutsch und Sprachverkümmerung; und bevor jemand nach Quellen fragt - ich komme aus der Gegend. (Dieser Gegensatz in verschiedenen Meinungen ist wohl auch der Grund, warum die Wikipedia immer schriftliche Belege fordert.) Bei uns im Gymnasium gab es dafür jedenfalls den Rotstift.

Comment: @feeela: Daher auch das "umgangssprachlich". Von Standarddeutsch, wie es in einem Schulaufsatz gefordert wäre, war ganz explizit nicht die Rede. Zumal man für diesen Fall die Angabe einer Region weglassen kann, da das *Standdarddeutsche* überall gilt.

Answer (score 4):

Auch bei uns in Südhessen ist das normale Umgangssprache, man spricht in diesem Zusammenhang auch vom *Hessischen Genitiv*. Auch ich, der der Hochsprache durchaus mächtig bin, sage z.B.

> Das ist dem Alex sein Rechner!

Comment: Ist *Gen**e**tiv* auch Dialekt oder war der *Gen**i**tiv* gemeint?

Comment: @amadeusamadeus Tja, wohl eher ein Vertipper...

Answer (score 2):

Im Moselfränkischen Sprachraum, also von Trier bis Koblenz, ist es auch üblich.

Answer (score 1):

Im Zusammenhang mit Computer klingt für mich eigentlich nur

> Dem Klaus sein Computer hat einen
>   Virus, eine Macke oder zu wenig
>   Speicher

richtig. Gibt es jemand, der das sauber mit Genitiv ausdrücken kann, ohne sich die Zunge abzubeißen?

Edit:

Nicht der Computer verursacht hier das Problem.

> Marias Computer ist zu langsam.

Hingegen scheinen Eigennamen, die auf **s** enden, verantwortlich zu sein.

Beispiele solcher Namen sind

> Hans, Klaus, Doris

Besonders bei Doris würde ich keinen Genitiv anwenden, sondern sagen

> Der Doris ihr Computer ist ... Der
>   Computer von Doris ---

Comment: *Der Computer von Klaus hat ...*?

Comment: Werden Konstruktionen mit von als Genetiv gewertet? Bezüglich natürlichem Sprachgefühl ist das kein Genetiv. Grammatiker sehen das eventuell anders.

Comment: Ich glaube auch, dass das kein Genitiv ist. Aber es vermeidet das gesprochen schlecht unterscheidbare Genitiv-s bei Wörtern, die auf s (z, sch usw.) enden und kann daher eine Alternative sein. Schriftlich, klar, steht dann ein Apostroph.

Comment: `Klaus' Computer hat den Virus`, `Doris' Computer ist defekt`. `Der Computer von Doris` wäre der Computer, den mir Doris geschenkt hat - er ist von Doris oder von Vobis, aber jetzt meiner. `Die Computer hatten mich in der kalten Fabrikhalle umzingelt. "Heißt es 'der', 'die' oder 'das' Doris?" bellten sie mir blechern entgegen. Nervös stottern verhaspelte ich mich sogleich: "Der Doris, Ihr Computer!"` Mein Todesurteil war besiegelt.`

Comment: Den Doris'schen Rechner hätte ich noch anzubieten. "Der Doris'sche Computer zeigt eine leichte Rauchentwicklung in Höhe der Grafikkarte".

Comment: Also dafür muß Doris aber schon prominent sein - sonst wäre das eine satirische Überhöhung. Wird nur für "wichtige" Leute benutzt, z.B. Boolesche Algebra.

Comment: Das hat nichts mit Berühmtheit zu tun. Wenn Doris einen speziellen Computer erfunden hat, dann ist es der Doris'sche Computer, selbst wenn nur fünf Personen Doris kennen sollten.

Answer (score 1):

Im Badischen Dialekt bzw. Umgangssprache habe ich die Form definitiv gehört, wobei ich nicht weiß, wie das betrachtet wird (als korrekt oder "schlechter Sprachgebrauch").

Comment: Jedenfalls nicht als deutsche Standardsprache, und darauf kommt's ja wohl an.

Answer (score 1):

Ich glaube, die Formel mit "dem sein" ist im ganzen deutschen  Sprachraum bekannt edit: und wird auch gebraucht. Sie ist allerdings nur Umgangssprache und hat nicht Eingang in geschriebene Sprache gefunden, obwohl manche versucht haben, es auch in der Schriftsprache zu verbreiten. Ich habe ein altes etymologisches Wörterbuch, so von 1910, mit dem Titel

- Dem deutschen Volk sein Wörterbuch.

Comment: Das lese ich als "gib dem Volk sein Wörterbuch!"

Answer (score 0):

Auch in Südbrasilien mit dem [Riograndenser Hunsrückische](https://www.facebook.com/Riograndenser-Hunsr%C3%BCckisch-366655020086673/) deitsche Dialekt/Sproch geht das ähnlich, ei ma' sääht jo:

> Dem Paul sein Auto iss nochmol kaputt ...
>
> Der Internetz ihre/seine Verbinnung in hieder Stadt iss üwerschlecht ...
>
> Dem Kind sein Millich/Milch iss net woorrem/warm ...