# Searching German Website with user feedback on regional usage of words and phrases

Tags: regional, reference

After seeing the question on the regional usage of a certain grammatical construction:

[In welchen Regionen ist die dem-sein-Form gebräuchlich?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/48/in-welchen-regionen-ist-die-dem-sein-form-gebrauchlich)

I remembered that there is a German website that lists dialect words and phrases and the region where they are used is found out by the users.

I would be quite happy if someone knows the link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Der [Atlas zur deutschen Alltagssprache](http://www.philhist.uni-augsburg.de/lehrstuehle/germanistik/sprachwissenschaft/ada/) führt jedes Jahr Befragungen zu ausgewählten regionalen Worten und grammatikalischen Besonderheiten durch und veröffentlicht die Ergebnisse.

Comment: Fühle dich umarmt und geküsst :) Das ist genau das, was ich suche.