# Origin of the dem–sein possessive

Tags: etymology, history, regional, possessive

Does anyone know the origin of the slang construct in the form of:

> dem Mann sein Hut

(in place of the standard “der Hut des Mannes”)? The colloquial form of “der Hut von dem Mann” has always made sense and feels right, but I’ve never really understood where the slang construct came from. Is it a twisted use of the dative showing ownership (like with *gehören* or something)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In welchen Regionen ist die dem-sein Form gebräuchlich?](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/48/in-welchen-regionen-ist-die-dem-sein-form-gebrauchlich)

Comment: One might speculate that it is of old Germanic origin, since the construct is shared by other Germanic languages; in Norwegian for instance, the normal possessive is "Mannen sin hatt".

Comment: @Takkat: I fail to understand why this is a duplicate. The other question covers the regional distribution, not *why* people use this form to indicate a possessive relationship in the first place. While some answers also address the history of usage of this form, I didn’t find any that addresses the grammatical origin.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: we may have to not only look at a question but also look at the **answers** to understand a possible duplicate nature of a Q&A. This question was closed **five years ago** by five different community members way before we decided to keep duplicates written in another language. Digging out ancient posts sometimes reveals prehistoric stuff that nowadays may be treated differently. Any good reason you had reopened it now, five years later?

Comment: @Takkat: Die von dir verlinkte Frage zielt auf die geographische Verbreitung dieser Form ab. Diese Frage hier will aber wissen, warum sich diese Form überhaupt entwickelt hat. Das sind für mich zwei völlig verschiedene Fragen.

Comment: @Kevin: Du hast schon so viele gute Antworten hier gegeben, dass ich davon ausgehen kann, dass du entweder Muttersprachler bist, oder zumindest Deutsch auf einem sehr hohen Niveau sprichst. Ich bitte dich daher, dir mal das aufmerksam durchzulesen: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/a/830/1487

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: die Herkunft ist in den Antworten zu der anderen auf Deutsch gestellten Frage eigentlich schon recht ausführlich behandelt. User Kevin war leider seit 3 Jahren nicht mehr hier. Man darf jetzt also nicht allzu viel erwarten...

Comment: @Takkat: *die Herkunft ist in den Antworten zu der anderen auf Deutsch gestellten Frage eigentlich schon recht ausführlich behandelt.* – Wo?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: z.B.: *Belegt sind sie seit althochdeutscher Zeit: „du uuart demo balderes uolon sin uuoz birenkit“ – „dem Fohlen sein Fuß“ (Merseburger Zaubersprüche).* - *dass der possessive Dativ z.B. im klassischen Latein und Griechisch eine Standardkonstruktion ist,* - wenn ihr das hier nochmal aufrollen möchtet, kein Problem, aber bitte mit englischen Antworten zu englischen Fragen. Ich hätte eine neue, frische Frage von einem noch aktiven Mitglied **wesentlich** besser gefunden, als eine längst verlassene Antiquität aus dem Keller zu holen.

Comment: Sorry, als ich die Antwort schreib, habe ich nicht auf das Datum der Frage geschaut. Ich halte auch nichts davon, Leichen wiederzubeleben.

Answer (score 1):

Ich hoffe, es ist in Ordnung, wenn ich auf Deutsch antworte.

Es gibt kein einheitliches Deutsch, und es gab auch niemals ein einheitliches Deutsch. Menschen mit Deutsch als Muttersprache haben bereits im Frühmittelalter Dialekte gesprochen, die von Region zu Region unterschiedlich waren. Geographisch nahe gelegene Regionen haben einander zwar beständig beeinflusst, was zu einer Angleichung geführt hat, gleichzeitig haben sich aber zu jeder Zeit praktisch überall lokale Variationen herausgebildet, die zu einer zunehmenden Diversitierung geführt haben.

Die beiden Mechanismen (Angleichung und Entstehung neuer Varianten) haben sich jahrhundertelang die Waage gehalten. Erst die Einführung der Schulpflicht, und später auch die Ausstrahlung überregionaler Radio- und Fernsehsendung, führten zu einem deutlich rascheren Voranschreiten der Vereinheitlichung der deutschen Sprache.

Trotzdem ist es aber noch immer so, das historisch gewachsene lokale Besonderheiten in der Alltagssprache allgegenwärtig sind.

Dialekte unterscheiden sich voneinander nicht nur durch eine andere Aussprache bestimmter Wörter, und durch ein zum Teil anderes Vokabular. Auch die Grammatik eines Dialekts unterscheidet sich typischerweise von der Grammatik anderer Dialekte, aber auch von der Grammatik der Standardsprache, die in diesem Zusammenhang als Dachsprache verstanden werden kann.

So enthält zum Beispiel der Dialekt, der meine eigentliche Muttersprache ist, keinen Genitiv, und in vielen Phrasen und Satzkonstruktionen fallen Dativ und Akkusativ zusammen, so dass mein Muttersprachen-Dialekt nicht 4 Fälle, sondern nur 2 1/2 hat. (Dafür enthält die Grammatik desselben Dialekts neben Einzahl und Mehrzahl noch Reste einer Zweizahl.)

Wenn nun eine Sprache keinen Genitiv enthält, muss man Besitzverhältnisse irgendwie anderes ausdrücken, und in dem gewählten Beispielsdialekt (und seinen Vorgängerformen) wird dafür eben seit Jahrhunderten der Dativ verwendet.

Das Dem-sein-Possessiv ist ein altes Relikt und Zeugnis der Unterschiedlichkeit der Ursprünge der heutigen modernen deutschen Sprache. Seine relativ große Verbreitung im deutschen Sprachraum ist zugleich ein Beleg dafür, dass diese Form früher, als die Standardisierung der deutschen Sprache noch nicht so weit vorangekommen war wie heute, in vielen Regionen einen Quasi-Standard dargestellt hat.

Wann genau, wo genau, und aus welchen speziellen Grund sich diese Variation entwickelt hat, lässt sich heute aber eben so schwer herausfinden, wie die Antwort auf die Frage, wann, wo und warum die deutsche Sprache z.B den Konjunktiv II entwickelt hat, oder warum man damit angefangen hat, beim Wechsel von Mittelhochdeutsch zu Neuhochdeutsch die Vokale in den Stammsilben zu dehnen.

Solche Entwicklungen passieren im Regelfall ganz ohne besondern Grund.

Comment: Tatsächlich ist es so, dass *ein Großteil der deutschen Dialekte* den Genitiv nicht oder nicht mehr kennt. Hochdeutsch ist hier also eher die Ausnahme.

Comment: Ich finde es unpraktisch, wenn jeder Leser auf Dein Profil schauen muss, um herauszufinden, dass Dein muttersprachlicher Dialekt wohl Grazerdeutsch ist, um zu wissen, ob man widersprechen darf, zustimmen muss oder keine Ahnung hat.

Comment: @userunknown: Genau das ist aber der Zweck eines Profils. In anderen Antworten habe ich bei ähnlichen Fragestellungen geschrieben, wo ich aufgewachsen bin, habe dann aber das Feedback bekommen, dass eh schon längst alle meine Lebensgeschichte kennen, und dass ich das nicht jedesmal schreiben soll.

Comment: Falls du es ganz genau wissen möchtest: Aufgewachsen bin ich in Weinitzen, das ist eine Nachbargemeinde von Graz. Meine Eltern sind aus der Oststeiermark (Mutter: Weiz, Vater: Riegersburg), mein Großvater war Volkskundler und Schriftsteller und hat auch Bücher in Oststeirischer Mundart verfasst: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_Schölnast

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Danke, so genau wollte ich es nicht wissen. Dass das Profil als Universalfußnote verwendet werden soll bestreite ich. Es stoßen ja immer neue User auf die Plattform, so dass man das, was zum Verständnis gehört, am besten einfach hinschreibt."So enthält zum Beispiel der oststeiermärkische Dialekt (...) so dass dieser (...)" wäre ohnehin viel kürzer.

Comment: @userunknown: Wenn schon, dann »*oststeirischer* Dialekt«. Wenn etwas zum politischen Land Steiermark gehört, ist es »steiermärkisch« (steiermärkische Landesregierung, steiermärkische Landesbahnen«). In allen anderen Fällen ist es *steirisch*: steirisches Kernöl, steirischer Wein, steirische Äpfel, steirische Harmonika, steirischer Herbst (ein Avandgardfestival), steirischer Dialekt, oststeirisches Hügelland, usw. Die Bürger der Steiermark sind daher auch keine *Steiermärker*, sondern *Steirer*.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Ich ahnte schon, dass ich da was falsch mache. Hier in Berlin haben wir ein "Märkisches Viertel", das ist schuld. :)