# Can the genitive relative pronoun be replaced with dative?

Tags: word-usage

In general, we know that

> Das Buch meiner Mutter

can be replaced by

> Das Buch von meiner Mutter

Can the same transformation be applied to genitive relative pronouns, eg can

> Ich sehe den Mann, dessen Buch rot ist

be converted to

> Ich sehe den Mann, das Buch von dem rot ist

(or some other variation)?

Comment: related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/48/in-welchen-regionen-ist-die-dem-sein-form-gebrauchlich

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wenn, dann wäre es:

> Ich sehe den Mann, von dem das Buch rot ist.

aber dass man es machen kann heißt nicht, dass man es soll. Im Gegenteil: Wann immer einem diese Von-Nutzung bewusst wird sollte man stattdessen den Genitiv nutzen.

> Der Mann, von dem das Buch rot ist, könnte auch eher der Autor sein.

Comment: Ich bin mit dir einverstanden. Ich war neugierig.

Comment: Umgangssprachlich würden sich einige im Volk auch dafür entscheiden: Ich sehe den Mann, dem sein Buch rot ist.