# In what regions do you say "Das ist mir"?

Tags: dialect, regional, possessive

To express possession you normally say

> Das gehört mir.

or

> Das ist meins.

But there are regions where people regularly say

> Das ist mir.

Which are these regions and is there are terminus technicus for this dialectic form?

Comment: Das ist mir... geläufig. Also in ripuarischen Dialekten kommt's vor.

Comment: Related: [In welchen Regionen ist die dem-sein-Form gebräuchlich?](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/48/in-welchen-regionen-ist-die-dem-sein-form-gebrauchlich)

Comment: Ich glaube, das im Schwäbischen gehört zu haben.

Comment: Ripuarisch. Definitely. I grew up near Cologne. I moved to Northern Germany to attend university. My friends helped me shift flats in the uni town from a furnished place to a new apartment. They needed to identify what was to stay and what they should pack. Friend: "Der Stuhl da?" - Me: "Der ist mir." - Friend: "Der ist **meiner**." - Me: "Nein, das ist nicht dein Stuhl. Der ist ***mir***!"  That pattern went on for a while until I clocked that they were correcting my grammar.

Comment: @teylyn, und wem war der Stuhl nun wirklich?

Comment: @teylyn: Very funny! :-)

Comment: @CarstenSchultz, mir natürlich. Der war nicht dem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a north-south difference, which means the north tends to deny the `ist mir` construction while the south (including Hesse, Thuringia and Saxonia) feels it as common phrase.[<sup>(1)</sup>](http://www.grammatikfragen.de/showthread.php?285-Sagt-man-quot-Das-ist-mir-quot-oder-quot-Das-ist-meins-quot-Ich-wurde-im-Norden-Deutschlands-entsetzt-angeschaut-als-ich-sagte-quot-Das-ist-mir-quot-.-Woran-liegt-das-Danke-im-Voraus!)[<sup>(2)</sup>](http://www.wer-weiss-was.de/dialekte/das-ist-mir-hessische-sprach-unart)[<sup>(3)</sup>](http://www.gutefrage.net/frage/grammatikfrage-heisst-es-das-ist-mir-oder-das-ist-meins)

The terminus is "Anzeige von Besitzverhältnissen mit dem Verb *sein*".

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether "possessive dative" is a current grammar term, but one might called the thing in this way. "Das ist mir"  - I would consider this use as regional and substandard, but I don't know in which regions this expression is used. But "Das ist doch dem Paul sein Fahrrad" is colloquial language. I even remember the title of an older dictionary: Dem deutschen Volk sein Wörterbuch.

I just see that Die Grammatik (Duden, 8th edition) also has the term "possessive dative". In the register: Dativ, possessiv. In paragraph 1275 Duden says that possessive dative has been known in the whole of the German speaking area for a long time, but it is not standard language ( Duden should add "in written language").

Comment: So you're saying that "Das ist mir" is said all over the country with similar frequency? I doubt that. "Dem sein" is one thing, "das ist mir" is another thing, even if they can be described with the same grammatical term.

Comment: I wrote "Das ist mir" is regional  and I don't know where it is said. Duden says the possessive dative is known everywhere, but he means constructions with dative + sein/e as in Das ist dem Maier sein Auto/seine Frau.

Comment: @rogermue... well, then I don't see how this is an answer because OP wanted to know WHAT regions this is asked in. The answer got accepted for some reason but I don't think it matches the question very well.

Comment: @Emanuel  I answered mainly the question is there an accepted term. At first I used a term I would use, but then I found that the Duden grammar uses this term as well. As to where "Das ist mir" one should consult the Deutscher Sprachatlas, but I hadn't the time.

Comment: @rogermue: It's frequently used in Swiss German. Since that is Alemannic language zone, I'd say you'd probably meet the expression in Southern Germany and Western Austria, too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm from Hesse(n) and I use "Das ist mir" all the time, even when I try not to.

Fun fact, I didn't know this wasn't standard German until I started university. I just thought it was colloquial. I wouldn't have written it down in an essay, but I thought it was used that way everywhere in Germany. Oops.

But "das ist meins" und "das gehört mir" still sound very stilted to me.