# Nutzung von "sein"

Tags: word-usage

Existiert ein Unterschied, wenn ich sage / Is there a Difference between saying

> "Peter sein Ball ..."

oder

> "Peters Ball ..."

"... ist rund."?

Answer (score 5):

Der Unterschied ist, dass

> Peters Ball

standardsprachlich korrekt ist,

> (dem) Peter sein Ball

aber nicht. Letztere Konstruktion kommt aber in einigen Dialekten vor, siehe [diese Frage zu „dem sein“](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/48/in-welchen-regionen-ist-die-dem-sein-form-gebr%C3%A4uchlich).

Answer (score 0):

Kommt darauf an. Wenn Du einen Genitiv ausdrücken willst, dann ist

> Peters Ball

korrekt und die Konstruktion mit "ihm seiner" nicht - zumindest nicht standardsprachlich.

Der folgende Satz ist jedoch korrekt, da ist es aber auch kein Genitiv:

> Was dem Peter sein Ball ist dem Paul sein Fahrrad