# Dativ oder Genitiv?

Tags: dative, genitive

Ich hatte letztens eine Auseinandersetzung mit meiner deutschen Freundin, weil sie fest davon überzeugt ist, dass in folgendem Satz unbedingt  der Genitiv erforderlich ist.

> Wir versaufen unserer Oma ihr Kleinhäuschen

Für mich wiederum ist es ein ganz normaler Satz mit den 3 Elementen ganz eindeutig zu erkennen

> Wir (Nom) versaufen unserer Oma(Dat) ihr Kleinhäuschen (Akk).

So wie ich es im Deutschunterricht gelernt habe.

> Wir

löst den Nominativ aus, denn wir macht hier die Aktion versaufen.

> ihr Kleinhäuschen

Wäre hier das direkte Objekt, also Akkusativ, denn es wird von "wir" direkt betroffen.

> Unserer Oma

Wäre hier das indirekte Objekt, welches von der Aktion, das Haus von uns zu versaufen indirekt betroffen wird, also ist hier der Dativ erforderlich.

Was wäre eurer Meinung nach hier besser?

Ich denke beide könnten gehen, grammatikalisch gesehen, aber sie meinte, es höre sich falsch an mit der Dativ Konstruktion an.

Comment: Zur Konstruktion siehe https://german.stackexchange.com/q/48/35111

Comment: Es ist definitiv kein Hochdeutsch und für meine Ohren würde ich ein deutlich aussagekräftigeres Wort als "falsch" wählen...

Comment: Wo ist jetzt die Alternative? Ich sehe nur einen Satz, mal mit, mal ohne Erläuterungsklammern. Auch hätte ich "ihr klein Häuschen." geschrieben.

Comment: Es geht also darum, ob "*unserer Oma*" hier im Genitiv oder Dativ steht, weil man das an den Endungen nicht erkennen kann, richtig? In solchen Fällen hilft es manchmal, ein Substantiv mit anderem Genus zu wählen und damit den Satz analog zu bilden. Verkauft doch mal Opas Häuschen! :)

Comment: Obligatorischer Verweis auf Tucholsky: [Ein deutsches Volkslied](http://www.zeno.org/Literatur/M/Tucholsky,+Kurt/Werke/1922/Ein+deutsches+Volkslied).

Answer (score 4):

[Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/versaufen) gibt für *versaufen* als Bedeutung an: *zu Geld machen und davon Alkohol kaufen, den man selbst trinkt*.

Der [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/versaufen) listet die Beispiele:

- den ganzen Lohn versaufen
- er hat seinen Verstand versoffen

Versaufen ist etwas, das man selbst tun kann. Aber man kann es niemandem antun.

*Unserer Oma* ist hier also nicht - wie von dir gedeutet -  das "indirekte Objekt, welches von der Aktion ... indirekt betroffen wird", 
sondern gehört zum Akkusativobjekt.

> unserer Oma ihr Kleinhäuschen (Akk.)

Die Formulierung ist also eine Possessiv-Konstruktion, die in [dieser Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/48/in-welchen-regionen-ist-die-dem-sein-form-gebr%C3%A4uchlich) ausführlich behandelt wird. Aus den dortigen Beiträgen geht auch hervor, dass sich die Frage

> Was wäre ... hier besser?

über bloße Meinungsäußerungen hinaus nicht beantworten lässt.

Ich gebe deiner Freundin insofern recht, als sich diese Dativkonstruktion auch für meine Ohren schräg anhört. Da sie aber in einigen Regionen offenbar sehr gebräuchlich und [in einigen Schweizer Dialekten offenbar sogar alternativlos](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/92/36196) ist, hielte ich es für vermessen, sie als **falsch** zu bezeichnen.

Als [Zeile eines Liedes](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wir_versaufen_unsrer_Oma_ihr_klein_H%C3%A4uschen) kann sie ohnehin nicht falsch sein, auch wenn ich denselben Sachverhalt hochdeutsch mit

> Wir versaufen das Häuschen unserer Oma.

ausdrücken würde.

Answer (score 0):

Ich bin sprachlich im Ruhrgebiet sozialisiert worden. Hier gibt es noch Reste eines alten niederdeutschen Substrats, die sich in der Umgangssprache teilweise bis heute gehalten haben. Bis auf den heutigen Tag trifft man hier auf Menschen, die ein anderes Kasussystem haben und z.B. bei der Anrede den Akkusativ als Vokativ benutzen oder beim Dativ auf einen 'Akkudativ' als Einheitskasus für Nicht-Nominativ ausweichen. (*Ey du Doowen, pass bloß auf, ich gipp dich gleich 'du Eierkopp'!*)

Vor diesem Hintergrund verstehe auch ich wie Olafant das gesamte *unser Oma ihr klein Häuschen* als Akkusativ. Darin ist *unser' Oma* ein Possessiv, eine gängige Konstruktion zur Genitivvermeidung. Man könnte hier z.B. auch sagen '*von unser Omma dat Haus*' oder '*von unsere Omma dat Haus*'.

> Der ***Oma ihr klein Häuschen*** ist hierzulande praktisch ein geflügeltes Wort für 'das Häuschen von der Oma' - vermutlich, weil der Titel des seinerzeit bekannten Karnevalsschlagers als Refrain bis zum Gehtnichtmehr wiederholt wurde.

Dazu ein aktuelleres Beispiel aus dem Hellweger Anzeiger: "Wenn Oma ihr klein Häuschen für die Pflege draufgeht" (30.08.2018, die Zeitung erscheint im Raum Dortmund - Unna - Kamen - Soest, also im Westfälischen.) Hier wurde auch die damit assoziierte Bedeutung 'ein wertvoller Besitz verliert jeden Wert' genutzt.

*Ihr klein Häuschen* ist klar Akkusativ, weil das Objekt von *etwas versaufen* im Akkusativ kommt. *Unser Oma* kann Akkusativ oder Dativ sein, aber nicht im Sinne eines Objekts zu *versaufen*, sondern als Teil einer Possessivkonstruktion. Analoge Konstruktionen wären *von mein Vatter die Cousine* = *den seine Cousine* (auch *von meim Vatter die Cousine = dem seine Cousine*); im Femininum stelle ich mir das eher als Akkusativ vor: *von meine Omma die Tante*, abgekürzt zu *von mein' Omma die Tante*; mit Dativ (*von meiner Omma die Tante*) wäre das praktisch hochsprachlich. Allerdings sagt man 'pronominal' begleitend (besser: 'determinierend') immer *der ihre Tante* und nie *die ihre Tante*.

Das Problem ist, dass hier heute weder Dialekt noch Hochdeutsch gesprochen wird, sondern verschiedene Zwischenformen, jedoch weitestgehend Hochdeutsch. Darum lässt sich der Kasus von 'unser Oma' je nach Dialekt'tiefe' anders auffassen. Für mein Regelbewusstsein handelt es sich weder um einen Pertinenzdativ ('Betroffenheitsdativ' wie bei 'man hat *ihr* den Führerschein weggenommen') noch eindeutig um einen possessiven Ersatzdativ für den Genitiv, sondern am ehesten um einen possessiven Ersatz-Akkudativ. Die meisten werden hier jedoch einen Ersatzdativ vermuten.

Hinzu kommt, dass bei einer Liedzeile das Versmaß stimmen muss, was mit ein Grund dafür gewesen wäre, die Endungen bei 'unser' und 'klein' wegzulassen. Solche Weglassungen gibt es sonst nur in formelhaftem Sprachgebrauch (z.B. 'auf *gut* Wetter machen').

Zur Bedeutung des Liedes ist bei [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wir_versaufen_unsrer_Oma_ihr_klein_H%C3%A4uschen) nachzulesen, dass es in der Zeit der Hyperinflation Anfang der 20er Jahre des letzten Jahrhunderts entstand. Die ursprüngliche Pointe '*unser Geld ist nichts wert*' wurde ab den 50ern im Westen zu einem reinen Hau-weg-auf-Ex-Saufschlager banalisiert.

Noch ein letztes dazu, was 'besser' wäre: Die Frage, wie der niederdeutsch beeinflusste Satz grammatisch aufzufassen ist, ist eine andere Frage als: *Wie kann man den Satz in gutes Standarddeutsch übertragen?* Das ist bereits beantwortet. Das Ergebnis *wir versaufen das Häuschen unserer Oma* ist jedoch inhomogen, denn 'versaufen' ist saloppe Umgangssprache und damit Substandard; die Redundanz des doppelt gemoppelten 'klein Häuschen' wurde zwar auf 'Häuschen' reduziert, aber ein Genitiv ist eher gutem bis gehobenem Standarddeutsch zuzuordnen. Letzteres ließe sich auch so lösen: *Wir versaufen das Häuschen von unserer Oma.* Ganz abwegig wäre eine Interpretation als *wir vertrinken unserer Oma kleines Haus*. Vorangestellte Genitivattribute gibt es nur in stehenden Wendungen wie *jeder ist seines Glückes Schmied* oder *das ist nicht jedermanns Sache*, ansonsten sind sie archaisierend und werden heute nur noch in sehr eingeschränktem Rahmen neu gebildet.

Comment: Das Lied wurde laut dem Wikipedia-Aritkel von einem in Berlin lebenden, gebürtigen Hamburger getextet und komponiert. Sollte man dann nicht eher einen der dortigen Dialekte zum Vergleich heranziehen statt dem des Ruhrgebiets?

Comment: @mtwde Es ging mir nicht um Vergleich, sondern darum, einmal darzustellen, wie ich als jemand, der im vormals niederdeutschen Sprachraum aufgewachsen ist und dessen Umgangssprache davon noch in geringem Maße beeinflusst ist, solche Sätze sozusagen spontan auffasse und mit welchen Phänomenen meiner eigenen Beobachtungen ich das in Verbindung bringe - welchen 'grammatischen Reim' ich mir darauf mache. Abgesehen davon wird, wie gesagt, im Ruhrgebiet kein Dialekt gesprochen, für Hamburg dürfte dasselbe gelten. Andererseits könnte eine ähnliche In-Beziehung-Setzung für Hamburg interessant sein.

Comment: @mtwde Dein Hinweis auf Hamburg ist jedoch nicht unwichtig, denn dadurch relativiert sich mein Fokus. Vielleicht sollte ich das Ganze noch einmal daraufhin durchgehen, dass es hier nicht darum, den Satz sozusagen fürs Ruhrdeutsch zu vereinnahmen.

Answer (score 0):

Neben der genannten possessiven Funktion (das Häuschen gehört der Oma), verstehe ich hier "der Oma" alternativ als Dativus Incommodi.

D. h., der Oma (Dativ) zum Nachteil versaufen wir ihr (possessiv) Häuschen.

Dass wir der Oma das Häuschen, das ihr gehört, versaufen, gereicht ihr zum Nachteil.