# what does "ich habe können" mean in Brecht, Berlin dialect?

Tags: modal-verb, northern-german

In Brecht 1970 Furcht und Elend des Dritten Reiches, page 16, we have

> DIE KÖCHIN Ich hole Ihnen noch ein Bier.
>
> DER SA-MANN Ist nicht nötig. Runterspülen hab ich können.

Runterspülen means to wash down food with a drink. But what does the sentence mean?

"I have already had a chance to wash down my food with a drink"?

[wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/haben_k%C3%B6nnen)---this link
deals with "haben können" but it appears the Brecht passage is "können haben".

Comment: "hab ich können" is in no discernable way Berlin or northern german dialect. It fits much better with Bavaria/Swabia where Brecht grew up. Compare for example the same grammar in this well-known aphorism by Munich comedian [Karl Valentin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl_Valentin) (which co-hosted a stage show with Brecht 1922 in Munich): „Mögen hätt’ ich schon wollen, aber dürfen hab ich mich nicht getraut“.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Ich hab(e) können* is the perfect of *können*, with [Ersatzinfinitiv](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/fragen/99) *können* instead of the expected past participle *gekonnt*. Whether *Ersatzinfinitiv* occurs or not is subject to some variation; when another infinitive is present – *runterspülen* in this instance – it is expected. The sentence is regular Standard German (although elision of the accusative object of *runterspülen* is somewhat rare).

> Ich habe (es) runterspülen können.
> *I was able to wash (it) down.*

Putting *runterspülen* in first position makes it the [topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic_and_comment).

Note that *können* + infinitive perfect is completely different: This would be the [epistemic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemic_modality) use of the modal.

> Ich weiß nicht, ob der Kollege noch da ist. Er kann auch schon Feierabend gemacht haben.
> *I'm not sure whether my colleague is still here. I think it's possible that he went home already.*

As opposed to:

> Er hat heute früher Feierabend machen können.
> *He was able to go home early today.*

Answer (score 2):

The sentence translates to:

> I was able to wash (it) down.

or, in closer analogy to the structure of the original sentence:

> Washing (it) down, I have been able to do.

The structure of the latter translation explains the structure in the German original.